# How to fix 'undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add an invoice and delete from cart in the same time so i use a method in cart controller to do the thing but i got this error but when i refresh the error is gone and i do not understand why. Iam sure that i am baddly developped that method but i do not no how to proceed diffrently. this is my code:

in paniers_controller(controller for cart)

```
def confirm
 @panier =Panier.find(params[:id])
 @facture= Facture.new(user_id: current_user.id, transaction_id: @panier.transaction_id, price: @panier.price, status: @panier.status, purchased_at: @panier.purchased_at )
 if @facture.save
   Panier.destroy(@panier.id)
   flash[:notice]='Votre facture est validée'
   redirect_to books_list_path
 end
end
```

in routes.rb:

```
post '/confirm/:id' => 'paniers#confirm', as: :facture_confirmation
```

in views/paniers/show.html.erb
`<%=link_to 'confirmer',facture_confirmation_path(@panier) ,method: :post, class: 'btn btn-success' %>`

that error is refering to

> @facture= Facture.new(user_id: current_user.id, transaction_id: @panier.transaction_id, price: @panier.price, status: @panier.status, purchased_at: @panier.purchased_at )

update:

this is what i got as error:

```
Started POST "/confirm/51" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-20 12:16:21 +0100
  Processing by PaniersController#confirm as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"2UFp7qnM6mykQWydeXYxVkO2om7WFIJKJDtejuaA6ZI=", "id"=>"51"}
  Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  Panier Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `paniers`.* FROM `paniers`  WHERE `paniers`.`id` = 51 LIMIT 1
 #<Panier id: 51, user_id: 6, created_at: "2014-11-20 11:12:30", updated_at: "2014-11-20 11:14:21", book_id: 13, price: 12, title: nil, quantity: 1, notification_params: nil, status: "Completed",  transaction_id: "3TK45927AJ5784644", purchased_at: "2014-11-20 11:14:21">
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms

 NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
```

Comment: I guess you should check the object @panier and what all data it contains

Comment: when i check my paniers table i found the record with the needed id

Comment: that is allright. But check the object @panier and what it contains. You can do that by typing `p @panier` in your controller and check its value in the server after reloading the page.

Comment: Can you post the full error backtrace?